# Microsoft Graph - PopAuthenticatorInvalidSignature errors when patching to calendar events

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

We're seeing errors with the graph api when making a `PATCH` request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/$(CALENDAR_ID)/events/$(EVENT_ID)`.

This is in an integration that has been in production for some time and we've never seen this before. Is this a bug with the api, downtime, or something we should handle on our end? Here's an example response:

```
HTTP 401
{
  "error": {
    "code": "PopAuthenticatorInvalidSignature",
    "message": "Signature is invalid for pop authenticator.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2019-09-25T18:33:37",
      "request-id": "1383b020-6ba0-44db-85b8-03cfbf277cd3"
    }
  }
}
```

Here are additional request ids:

```
0c2a47da-1090-4c06-b5cb-fc95b3964913
7403116f-3edd-4d39-adf9-51ed2feaee23
27df39b8-43ad-41f8-b9f1-b5e2adaafb4b
408c8686-bf78-4a82-883a-7e794838d846
7130b609-1a0a-46f2-b523-0db1db591fe1
9659a797-180f-4f41-bba0-b1b490408752
161ea8d8-dcf5-4f0d-aa21-32b584e22ba6
```

Happy to provide additional information if needed.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, just started today for me also. I am using the beta endpoint and using app authentication (if that helps).

Comment: Also seeing a similar error when trying to query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/.../messages` -- just started in the last hour or two for us.

Comment: Yeah - seeing the same thing and a few colleges are as well. This looks to be some sort of outage in o365 land.

Comment: Same thing on our end, starting 30 minutes ago or so.

Comment: Same thing here in NZ

Comment: Same here. Lots of users getting errors out hitting the Graph API for accessing mail and calendar.

Comment: Same here too. I've tested with different users, and some of them are working fine while others receive 401 error

Comment: We hit the Graph API retrieving emails every 15 seconds. Problem started Sep 26 2019 17:57 UTC and continued till 22:13 UTC. The service worked intermittently during that period. Calls have worked for two hours now since that last error. I'm in Australia.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a server side issue that's now been rectified.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this exact issue across multiple customers' Graph applications. It's been sporadic since at least yesterday and as of roughly 17:30 Central today, it's stopped happening completely. It certainly looks like some sporadic API outage/issue.

We have not re-registered any applications - it just stopped failing on its own. We've encountered this issue with apps that have been registered with both the old and the new app registration system, so I don't think it's related at all.

I read the deprecation notice on the old app registration portal as saying that the old **portal** is deprecated, not that any previously registered apps are deprecated and need to be re-registered. Microsoft would never silently break nearly everyone's API access like that.

Answer (score -3):

I think I got an answer.  Looks like Microsoft has deprecated an old way of registering applications.  If you go to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com you will see the deprecation message and also will find a link where you can handle it.

I did it and my application is working again.